# Writing huge XML files with StAX

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have some data (about 150-200 MB) which I need to convert into an XML file. I previously tried doing it based on DOM, but memory is a big constraint.

I started looking at the StaX implementation and have a few queries.

Lets say I have the following code.

```
  XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("output.xml"));
  writer.writeStartDocument("  ");
  writer.writeStartElement(" ");
  writer.writeStartElement("");
  // call method X a million times
  writer.writeEndElement(" ");
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();

  // method x
  X() {
     writer.writeStartElement("  ");
     writer.writeEndElement();
  }
```

1. I am assuming that whenever method X is executed , it writes the element into the file. This wont hold the converted XML until now in memory. Am I right?
2. Will this close the unclosed tags automatically like the first 2 start elements?
3. Can I flush the writer and use the same writer again to append some more xml into the file like this:

   ```
   X() 
   {
       writer.writeStartElement("  ");
       writer.writeEndElement();
       writer.flush();
   }
   ```

Comment: Is you XML structure very complex (lots of different types nodes and a deep hierarchy)?

Comment: Yes. The data is dynamic and we need to create the XML based on the data

Comment: Ok. I thought would be just a data parsing. So, maybe you would consider doing it by hand with a lightweight StringBuffer. I do not have a answer for #1 or #2, but I have a feeling that you will have issues. Have you considered JAXB?

Comment: JAXB sounds precisely like what the OP is trying to avoid, since it requires you have all the data in memory.

Comment: Use `factory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.xml"), "UTF-8")`. A FileWriter uses the default (OS) encoding. Better still a GzipOutputStream on file output.xml.gz with compression.

Answer (score 2):

> I am assuming that whenever method X is executed , it writes the
>   element into the file. This wont hold the converted XML until now in
>   memory. Am I right?

The StAX parser may buffer a subsets of the XML in memory before writing it to a file to reduce the amount of disk I/O done to improve performance.  It won't cache so much that you run out of memory.

> Will this close the unclosed tags automatically like the first 2 start
>   elements?

The `writeEndDocument` method will close any unclosed tags automatically.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeEndDocument()

> Can I flush the writer and use the same writer again to append some
>   more xml into the file like this:

You can keep using the same `XMLStreamWriter` to write content to an XML file until you call `writeEndDocument`.  You don't need to explicitly call `flush` before you write more content.  Once you are done with the `XMLStreamWriter` you should call `close` on it to free it up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but you should buffer some (small) writes in a buffer. You should use the BufferedWriter in addition to the FileWriter. Otherwise it makes too many system calls for instance.
2. It writes end-tags once you call writeEndElement().
3. Yes, that should be the way to go.